# ios - in-app purchase error code 3 "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I followed apple's guide to implement in-app purchases and when i try to purchase something i get error code 3 and the description `Cannot connect to iTunes Store`.

I tried to dump the network from the phone and it appears that the phone connects correctly to the sandbox. I also tried adding a new user and i signed out of the store.

I don't even get the screen to enter my test user... just the error above.

help

Comment: Are you testing on a device, or the simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add my bank account and tax info in itunes connect.

That solved the problem.

Comment: I can confirm that with error code 3, and "can't connect to itunes store" as the error messages what was missing was the bank account information.